# How to set ReadBarcodes properly

Tags: c#, leadtools-sdk

I am trying to read a 3of9 barcode. 
[3of9 barcode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS1I5.png)
the result that is giving me is inconstant but the location is still the same. (tried running that method multiple times same Image/barcode and same position)
What I mean by inconstant is sometimes I am getting the value of the barcode
ex. 
barcodesd.Length is not zero so it is getting the barcodesd[0].Value which is 
25350111
and sometimes the barcodesd.Length = 0

here is my code:

```
public static string DecodeImg(System.Drawing.Bitmap img)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream();
            RasterImage srcImage = null;
            try
            {

                BarcodeEngine engine = new BarcodeEngine();
                Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs codecs = new Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs();

                img.Save(data, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                data.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                srcImage = codecs.Load(data);
                BarcodeData[] barcodesd = engine.Reader.ReadBarcodes(srcImage, LeadRect.Empty, 0, BarcodeEngine.GetSupportedSymbologies(), null);
                srcImage.Dispose();
                if (barcodesd != null)
                {
                    if (barcodesd.Length > 0)
                        return barcodesd[0].Value;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                data.Dispose();

                if (srcImage != null)
                    srcImage.Dispose();
            }

            return "Unable to Read";
        }
```

Comment: `throw ex.Message;` doesn't compile.

Comment: okay edit the question. My bad with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The barcode in the image is not properly encoded. It appears whoever (or whatever) generated it tried to insert 2 asterisk "*" characters inside it.
The "*" character is not a true encodable character, but is the start and stop symbol for Code 3 of 9 barcodes. This means it should not be inserted inside the barcode string.

Since there are 2 such "*" characters inside the code, a reader might be able to "find" the middle portion and consider it a valid barcode on its own. But that is not predictable since the encoding of the entire code is incorrect.

If you believe the code is valid, and you have evidence to that from any source (for example, a different barcode reader can consistently recognize it), please send the images you have to support@leadtools.com and provide full details about your findings. Also include information about which version of the SDK and which platform you’re using (for example v20, 64-bit C# WinForms).

Comment: Thank you... Yes I have consulted now with support of leadtools regarding this issue.